# Android Issue Logging ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to read `ArrayList` data using *Log*, but not getting data in a proper manner.

Getting something *like* this:

```
D/Records:Button--: [RecordsListItem@42937738, RecordsListItem@42772588]
```

Code:

```
ArrayList<RecordsListItem> records;

----------------

records = new ArrayList<RecordsListItem>();

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.d("Records:Button--", records.toString());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `toString()` from the `ArrayList` **object** . If you want to log all objects in the ArrayList you have to iterate it:

```
for ( RecordsListItem singleRecord : records)
{
   Log.d("Records:Button--", singleRecord.toString());
}
```

Note that with this way you are calling the `toString()` method of each `RecordsListItem` stored in the ArrayList. Maybe is better that you override the `toString()` method in your `RecordsListItem` class.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

To print data of arraylist you can do any of this two :

1) Override toString method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data [NAME=" + NAME + ", CLASS=" + CLASS + ", THIRTY=" + THIRTY
            + ", NINETY=" + NINETY + "]";
}
```

2) `ArrayList<Data>` array is collection of Data objects. You have to specify which object you want to print. You can do that in two ways.

```
int index = 0;// Index of object in the ArrayList
Log.i("Data",array.get(index).toString());//Preferred Method to get object
Log.i("Data",array.toArray()[index].toString());
```

You can loop through your array to print all Data objects like this

```
for (Data data : array) {
    Log.i("Data",data.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this, first change it to regular list or Array the log it

```
 Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(myList.toArray()))
```